# Received output from linux terminal is blank (SSH)

Tags: c#, ssh

This piece of code executes a command to the raspberry pi terminal and then receives the output. The command is executed successfully but the received output is blank.

```
private void sendSSHCommand(string command)
{          
        SshClient cSSH = new SshClient("IP","PORT","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
        cSSH.Connect();

        try
        {
           SshCommand x = cSSH.RunCommand(command);
           MessageBox.Show(x.Result); //I GET A BLANK MESSAGEBOX
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           //error
        }

        cSSH.Disconnect();
        cSSH.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Does `command` execute without error? It is common on linux to write error messages to `stderr`. In this case `x.Result` would be empty, but `x.Error` would contain the error message.

Comment: What command are you executing? What actual string is in `command`? What output does it normally produce?

Comment: @ChristianHeld yes the command is executed without error

Comment: @Kenster I have installed playerctl on my raspberry pi which allows me to control VLC media player. I sucessfully execute the command "playerctl status" which outputs the current state of the media player (paused, playing, stopped) but instead i recieve blank text